# Problems with Intel Core 2 Duo E4300

Tags: cpu, fan, intel-core2

I've got this 4 year old computer. It wasn't mine, but I know that the computer was working for long time.

```
Motherboard Name - Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3
DIMM1: Kingston (1 GB DDR2-667 DDR2 SDRAM)
CPU Type - DualCore Intel Core 2 Duo E4300, 1800 MHz (9 x 200)
```

and original cooler:

[image: FAN]

So the problem is that when computer starts the fan spins and stops. And a lot of times. It starts to spinning normally when BIOS posts. But today all was same except the fan started to spin normally only when Windows XP started to booting.

The CPU temperature is normally about 50 C, when Windows 7 is running with enabled Aero in VirtualBox the CPU temperature reaches 63C. The computer by itself is quiet. I don't see any dust on the fan, but Im not sure about the heatsink. I have changed PSU from 350 watt to 650 watt.

Why the fan acting so strange when computer starts, maybe I can change something in BIOS?

Comment: 63C is not hot for a processor.  Perhaps the fan isn't running because it doesn't need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the BIOS, there is an option called "CPU Smart FAN Control" which allows the PC to automatically vary the speed with temperature or to allow the user to control the speed  through a utility.    The initial fan spin up is likely to be part of the Power On Self Test.

Mainboard manual [here](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2325#manual), see page 42